# Is there a way to receive sub-precision touch events on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

When `-touchesMoved:withEvent:` gets called I receive only rounded numbers from `[touch locationInNode:self];`.

Is there a way to receive more precise events? I tried upscaling and downscaling UIWindow and the view which receives the events.

Did someone found a trick that gives higher precision events?

Comment: Higher precision? I assume a CGPoint isn't high enough? What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: gestureRecognizers would be another way to get events but they use CGPoints too so the precision is probably the same.  `CGPoint loc = [gesture locationInView: gesture.view];`

Comment: You should be getting half precision with a retina screen (.5) and whole for non. Are you expecting the touch sensor to be more precise than .5 point (1 pixel)?

Comment: Yes, subpixel precision is desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying, you want better-than-pixel precision for your touch events. But touch events always come in as per-pixel. The touch screen wouldn't be accurate enough to tell you that you touched halfway between two rows of pixels, and your finger is easily touching an area multiple pixels wide anyway. I don't think you can do anything to "trick" it into giving you some kind of more accurate precision.

Comment: It might be points, so you might only have the same precision on retina as on non-retina. But still, it's still fairly high precision. And if you think about it, it's still just a pixel approximately in the middle of where your skin contacts the screen, so the margin of error on where you actually touched is greater than a point anyway.